# How do I get the index out of the optional func didMoveToPage?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using uacaps/CAPSPageMenu in my app and I cannot figure out how to get the number of the active page so I can show a webpage corresponding to the page. In the code CAPSPageMenu.swift the following code is used.

```
import UIKit

@objc public protocol CAPSPageMenuDelegate {
// MARK: - Delegate functions

optional func willMoveToPage(controller: UIViewController, index: Int)
optional func didMoveToPage(controller: UIViewController, index: Int)
}
```

I think the index: Int part in the optional func didMoveToPage is giving me a number of the current page. Is this right? How do I get that index number in the ViewController.swift code?

**EDIT**
In CAPSPageMenu I found this code.

```
public func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.isEqual(controllerScrollView) {
        // Call didMoveToPage delegate function
        let currentController = controllerArray[currentPageIndex]
        delegate?.didMoveToPage?(currentController, index: currentPageIndex)
```

The ViewController.swift code as shown below.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  PageMenuDemoStoryboard
//
//  Created by Niklas Fahl on 12/19/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 CAPS. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit


var websiteArray = ["http://website_0", "http://website_1", "http://website_2"]


//class ViewController: UIViewController {
class ViewController: UIViewController,CAPSPageMenuDelegate {

var pageMenu : CAPSPageMenu?
var pageNumber = 0

@IBOutlet weak var showWebsite: UIWebView!

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)


    // MARK: - UI Setup
    self.title = "App Title"
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 30.0/255.0, green: 30.0/255.0, blue: 30.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.orangeColor()]

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "<-", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: "didTapGoToLeft")
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "->", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: "didTapGoToRight")


    // MARK: - Scroll menu setup

    // Initialize view controllers to display and place in array
    var controllerArray : [UIViewController] = []

    let controller1 : TestCollectionViewController = TestCollectionViewController(nibName: "TestCollectionViewController", bundle: nil)
    controller1.title = "Item_0"
    controller1.photoNameArray = ["Item_0.png"]
    controllerArray.append(controller1)
    let controller2 : TestCollectionViewController = TestCollectionViewController(nibName: "TestCollectionViewController", bundle: nil)
    controller2.title = "Item_1"
    controller2.photoNameArray = ["Item_1.png"]
    controllerArray.append(controller2)
    let controller3 : TestCollectionViewController = TestCollectionViewController(nibName: "TestCollectionViewController", bundle: nil)
    controller3.title = "Item_2"
    controller3.photoNameArray = ["Item_2.png"]
    controllerArray.append(controller3)


    // Customize menu (Optional)
    let parameters: [CAPSPageMenuOption] = [
        .ScrollMenuBackgroundColor(UIColor(red: 30.0/255.0, green: 30.0/255.0, blue: 30.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)),
        .ViewBackgroundColor(UIColor(red: 20.0/255.0, green: 20.0/255.0, blue: 20.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)),
        .SelectionIndicatorColor(UIColor.orangeColor()),
        .BottomMenuHairlineColor(UIColor(red: 70.0/255.0, green: 70.0/255.0, blue: 80.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)),
        .MenuItemFont(UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 13.0)!),
        .MenuHeight(30.0),
        .MenuItemWidth(90.0),
        .CenterMenuItems(true)
    ]

    // Initialize scroll menu
    pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.height * 0.71, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height * 0.33), pageMenuOptions: parameters)

    self.addChildViewController(pageMenu!)
    self.view.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)

    pageMenu!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    pageMenu!.delegate = self


    func willMoveToPage(controller: UIViewController, index: Int) {
        let subview=controller as! ViewController
        subview.pageNumber=index;
    }

}


func didTapGoToLeft() {
    var currentIndex = pageMenu!.currentPageIndex

    if currentIndex > 0 {
        pageMenu!.moveToPage(currentIndex - 1)
    }
    setWebPage()
}


func didTapGoToRight() {
    var currentIndex = pageMenu!.currentPageIndex

    if currentIndex < pageMenu!.controllerArray.count {
        pageMenu!.moveToPage(currentIndex + 1)
    }
    setWebPage()
}


func setWebPage() {
    var currentIndex = pageMenu!.currentPageIndex
    switch currentIndex {
    case 0:
        let url = NSURL (string: "\(websiteArray[0])");
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
        showWebsite.loadRequest(requestObj);
        break

    case 1:
        let url = NSURL (string: "\(websiteArray[1])");
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
        showWebsite.loadRequest(requestObj);
        break

    case 2:
        let url = NSURL (string: "\(websiteArray[2])");
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
        showWebsite.loadRequest(requestObj);
        break

    default:
        break
    }
}


// MARK: - Container View Controller
override func shouldAutomaticallyForwardAppearanceMethods() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func shouldAutomaticallyForwardRotationMethods() -> Bool {
    return true
}
}
```

When I tap the buttons it is working like it should. The navigation bar shows the active page and the picture (collectionViewController) that belongs to the active page is shown and also the webpage that belongs to the active page is shown. But I do not want to use the buttons. I want to use the collectionViewController so that when I swipe the image to the next page the new image is shown (this is working already) and the corresponding webpage also (this is not working because of not setting the *pageMenu!.currentPageIndex*).
How to activate the didTapGoToLeft and Right methods when I swipe the picture?

Comment: The delegate method also receives the viewcontroller, so make sure that your UIViewController subclass has a property for the page number, cast `controller` to your subclass and simply assign index to the property

Comment: Thank you for your comment, when I am at home this night I will try it. Do not completely understand your answer but that is because of I am a newbe to IOS. First I want to try things on my own (thats better for learning I think) but maybe I will ask another question if I cannot get it working. Hope you do not mind.

Comment: @Paul  
Have tried it but did not get it working, partly because of my knowledge. I have edited my original question and added some more information.

Comment: You have (at least) two view controller classes - The main view controller that contains the CAPSPageMenu instance and the view controller class(es) that you are putting inside the page menu.  In your main view controller you implement the delegate methods from your question.  In those delegate methodsyou assign the page index to the controller that was passed to the delegate method.

Comment: @Paulw11  Thank you for your reply. I am afraid that I need to learn more about the terminology used in swift. Tonight I am going to try it again. The code CAPSPageMenu.swift contains the code which is handling how the app is working. The code ViewController.swift is used to call the CAPSPageMenu like this: pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(all the properties inside the brackets). Also in the ViewController.swift I am connecting the pictures and texts in a controllerArray. So I see the ViewController.swif code as my main view controller. I do not know how I can implement the delegate in the main control

Comment: @Paulw11  Sorry but after trying several things I still do not know how to figure it out. Can you show me some code to make your comments more visible to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CAPSPageMenu provides a delegate method that inform's its delegate that the page has changed.  These are the delegate methods you listed in your question.

So, in your ViewController class you need to implement these delegate methods.

First, tell the compiler that your class implements the protocol:

```
class ViewController:UIViewController,CAPSPageMenuDelegate
```

Now, you need to set the view controller as the delegate.  Where you create the CAPSPageMenu you will need something like this -

```
pageMenu.delegate=self
```

Finally, implement the delegate methods.  The CAPSPageMenu is provided with an array of view controllers that it manages.  You haven't given the precise details of these, but I am assuming that they implement some class which I am calling `SubViewController`.  Define an integer property `pageNumber` in this class and then your delegate method can simply be -

```
func willMoveToPage(controller: UIViewController, index: Int) {
    let subview=controller as! SubViewController
    subview.pageNumber=index;
}
```

Then, in your SubViewController you can implement a setter on `pageNumber` that does whatever it needs to when the page number changes.  In your delegate method you could also use the index to index into an array of strings (URLs say) and then set a string/URL property on the sub view controller - it depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: In my project there are 3 codes that are taking care of the app.
1 = ViewController.swif
2 = CAPSPageMenu.swift
3 = TestCollectionViewController.swift
  In the original question I have placed the whole ViewController.swift code. As far as I can see all the things you mentioned must be placed inside this code. If the code is good then what is triggering the method willMoveToPage? Because I can not see that subview.pageNumber is changing.

Comment: You have declared `willMoveToPage` inside `viewDidAppear`. You need to move this function declaration outside of that function so that it is an instance function like all of the others. Also your app will appear more smoothly if you use the function `viewWillAppear` rather than `viewDidAppear`

Comment: Placed it outside the `viewWillApear` code but I am still asking myself what is triggering the 'willMoveToPage' function. In the ViewController.swift code you can find `var controllerArray : [UIViewController] = [ ]` and I think that it should be something like this.  `IF controllerArray (currentNumber) is not equal to controllerArray (previousNumber) THEN activate function willMoveToPage`. But I do not know if this is possible because I do not know how to get the numbers out of the `controllerArray` which is build up of `[UIViewController]`

Comment: That method is a delegate method. It is called by the CAPSPageMenu instance as your view controller is this objects delegate (`pageMenu!.delegate=self`)

Comment: Are you getting tired of me yet? Sorry for that. In the current situation I can start the app but when I swipe an image or select a menu item, so that the corresponding image is shown, the app crashes with the following error.  _Could not cast value of type 'PageMenuDemoStoryboard.TestCollectionViewController' to 'PageMenuDemoStoryboard.ViewController'_ I am trying to find out how to solve this. Next time I will make an app from scratch by myself. Then the limitations are my knowledge. This template is giving me so much issues because of my knowledge.

Comment: This is telling you that the view controllers that you have are instances of `TestCollectionViewController` but you tried to cast them `as! ViewController` - because the types are different the forced downcast failed

Comment: That last tip did the trick. It is working now! I will analyze the code so I understand better how it works. You helped me a lot the last days and I want to thank you for that! I really appreciate it.

Comment: In my case, i have 3 Menu as 3 controllers, which has API calling in view did load. When i am tapping on menu sequentially, then it's working fine but when i am tapping on last menu directly, its got crashed. Please help!